# Working with variables in nginx configuration on docker leads to too many redirect error when using variables

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I have created the following config (see below) in an nginx running in docker as proxy for Odoo. I used the `set $targeturl http://management:8069/;` as suggested here https://prds98.com/post/49/ to avoid that nginx container does not start up when the container it is pointing to (called management) is not running yet, and the name cannot be resolved. This solution works, but, leads to a "too many redirects error" in the browser when going to that URL.

When I remove the variable and just use `proxy_pass http://management:8069/;` it all works fine (if that container is running when starting nginx). What is the difference between the two because I thought it was just a variable definition and using it... so why does it lead to an error too many redirects when using it?

```
{
    ...
    server {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s ipv6=off;
        listen      80;
        server_name management.kbcodoo.test;

        proxy_read_timeout 720s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
        proxy_send_timeout 720s;

        # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        # log
        access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;
    
        # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
        location / {
            set $targeturl http://management:8069/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass $targeturl;
        }   
        location /longpolling {
            set $targeturllong http://management:8072/;
            proxy_pass $targeturllong;
        }

        # common gzip
        gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
        gzip on;            
    }
}
```